# using wget on a link with japanese characters will give 404

Tags: wget

i used wget on a website and all files were downloaded without errors. the pages that has this type of link:

- website.com/english/apple
- website.com/english/dog
- website.com/english/baby

were downloaded and working properly.
however other files with link:

- website.com/japanese/おと
- website.com/japanese/ょうき

were downloaded and they all have the default 404 response page from the site. (it doesn't literally say 404, it just says something like "you typed the link wrong")

i tried using the command "--restrict-file-names=ascii" but the same thing happened.

note:after using the command the downloaded files had bad utf-8 codes. (one of them is %C3%A5%C2%A4%E2%80%A2 when decoding it, it will give gibberish)

i did some searching and [someone mentioned that](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=411290#22): "

> "wget url-encodes bytes 128-159 (which are control characters in some
>   8-bit encodings). This is wrong"

is that related to my problem?

Comment: Are you downloading the files by specifying their direct URLs on the command line, or by letting wget follow links in recursive mode?

Comment: no, wget is downloading links automatically. i just typed the name of website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a solution on a random Japanese blog. found it in the second page on google!!

just add `--local-encoding=UTF-8`

the full command that i used and worked for me is:

```
wget -m -np -c -R "index.html*" --restrict-file-names=ascii --local-encoding=UTF-8 "https://www.website.com/"
```